# Sums in loop using list Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

Input data will contain the total count of pairs to process in the first line.
The following lines will contain pairs themselves - one pair at each line.
Answer should contain the results separated by spaces.

data:
3

100 8

15 245

1945 54

answer:
108 260 1999

Comment: Please read this: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to store your values in a list:

```
my_list = []

data = int(input())

for i in range(data):
    z = input()
    y = input()
    my_list.append(z + " " + y)

for i in range(data):
    print(my_list[i])
```

Comment: or do you want the two values to be separate as in using a dictionary rather than a list?